# Cannot find javax ApplicationPath

Tags: java, netbeans

I have this simple java web service project that was previously working, but since i reinstalled my netbeans, javax.ws was not recognized, so i downloaded javax.ws jar and added to the project. But now i have this new error at

```
        @javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("webresources")
         public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {
```

Cannot find symbol.
symbol: class ApplicationPath
location: package javax.ws.rs

Im running netbeans 8.2 and JDK 1.8.0_144.

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar issue and after adding Java EE 6 API library, issue gets resolved.
myProject->Properties->Libraries->Add Library